# Lost Sound after power shortage

Tags: windows-7, laptop, audio, 64-bit

I forgot my laptop in sleep mode yesterday, and since my battery is dead, someone from the house removed the AC Adapter and the PC turned off, when i turned it on this morning, there was no sound, there is no red cross on the sound icon in the notification bar, that one is fully functional as i can increase/decrease volume, but there is no sound coming of the speakers, i tried with my headphones, but still nothing, I've checked my Control Panel and the speakers are already set to default, but nothing comes out, i also tried uninstalling and reinstalling the drivers, and the problem persists, i rebooted 7 times to no avail, can anyone help me on this matter ?

I use a Intel Core i3 M380 DELL INSPIRON N5010 running Windows 7 ultimate x64 bits on 4GB of ram, Intel HD Graphics 2000, my Sound Card uses IDT High Definition Audio Codec that i got from Dell's Website. If you guys need any more info please let me know I'll be monitoring this thread by the second.

EDIT:----------------------
Ok so after finding a fix to this issue, it turns out that it's temporary, and i have to access the Bios every time and save then exit to enable sounds, gets pretty annoying.

Comment: This is just a shot in the dark but did the on board sound get disabled in the BIOS?

Comment: @krowe ok so the problem seems to persist, it seems that i have to get into the Bios and "Save settings then Exit", every time i turn on the laptop, if i don't do that i won't have any sounds. I will edit my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say it's because your PC was out of charge, and the power shortage made the CMOS nearly ran out of battery but can still be used to hold for a day or shorter. So that the BIOS settings resets everytime you boot. Maybe try replacing the battery, it can be bought in any local tech shop. Here is how: http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000239.htm

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but as you can see my battery is already FULLY dead, as in empty and won't charge anymore.

Comment: @Omarrrio I believe he is talking about your CMOS battery; not the main laptop battery. The CMOS battery is a small non rechargeable battery on the main board. It's only job is to keep the CMOS alive between boots.

Comment: Aaaaah i see well i will try ti buy a new one soon